# Android Dialog Custom Layout for ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, dialog, android-dialog, customdialog

I have a dialog that's working fine. However, I want to change the size of the text and style of the dialog. Is there a quick way to do it without creating a custom dialog? I tried to apply a theme to do it, but it only changes the title text, but not the individual elements where the text is big and the size of the dialog is too big. Thanks.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builderSingle = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    builderSingle.setTitle("Select Item");
    final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = listAllItems(getActivity());

    builderSingle.setNegativeButton(
        "cancel",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    builderSingle.setAdapter(
        arrayAdapter,
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                String strName = arrayAdapter.getItem(which);
            }
        });
    builderSingle.show();
```

Comment: You're creating the `Adapter`, which means you can specify whichever item layout you want.

Comment: how do I create that layout with a simple text and reference it (and the individual row)?

Comment: Create a file in `res/layout/` - e.g., `dialog_list_item.xml` - that's just a `TextView`, styled however you want. Then pass `R.layout.dialog_list_item` as the second argument in the `ArrayAdapter` constructor call.

Comment: so I need to create a custom adapter? I tried  final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
          getActivity(),
          android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice);, but then how you pass my list listAllItems to the arrayadapter?

Comment: Your `listAllItems()` method is returning an `ArrayAdapter`, so one must be instantiated in that method. That's where you'd pass your `R.layout` instead of the `android.R.layout`; wherever you're instantiating the `ArrayAdapter`, not there where you're calling `listAllItems(getActivity())`.

Comment: that works, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
Listview lst_state;
TextView text_t ;
LayoutInflater inflater = mactivity.getLayoutInflater();
    View alertLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview, null);
    lst_state = (ListView) alertLayout.findViewById(R.id.listview_show_like_member_we);
    text_t = (TextView) alertLayout.findViewById(R.id.text_title);
    text_t.setText("State");
    lst_state.setAdapter(adapter_state);
    final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alert.setView(alertLayout);

    alert.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    final AlertDialog dialog = alert.create();
    lst_state.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            location_t_district.setText(arrayList_state.get(position).getStatename));
           dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    dialog.show();
```